# How to re-establish the link between SSIS parameters configured at the project level and at the job level?

Tags: ssis

SSIS package parameters can be configured in 2 places.

1. Under Integration services catalog - on the project (right click, configure).
2. Under the SQL agent job step package configuration.

Parameters configured at project level automatically show up at the job level, and also the job level picks up any parameter changes made at the project level.

Where as if change is made to the parameter at the job level, then this doesn't update at the project level.

Suppose you change the value of the parameter at job level, then even if you reset the value to the original value (to match with the project level value), then any subsequent changes to this parameter at the project level doesn't update the value at the job level. Is there any way to re-establish the link between the project level and job level parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand the question but let me know if I've missed the mark.

I have a project parameter, MagicNumber.
In the SSIS project in VS, it's -1.

I deploy to the SSISDB to a folder called `Demo` and Configure the deployed Project to have a value of 0. If I right click and run that package or create a job to run the package, it's going to use value of 0.

In a SQL Agent job, I then re-define MagicNumber to be 1 for all executions of that job. Even if I then go back into Configure the project to have 2 as my MagicNumber, all instances of this job will use 1 because we've specified that we are overriding the configured value.

If I created Job2 which runs the same package, it will use 0 and then 2 as MagicNumber because it's picking up the override from the Project Configuration.

Were you to deploy the same original .ispac file to a different folder, `Pristine` and ran that package, it's going to use -1 because that's the default configured value.

We put the first layer of configuration on all runs of the package from our project in the Demo folder by specifying MagicNumber is 0 and then 2. But the job allows us to add yet another layer of configuration by using a job specific level of configuration, 1.

If you decide 1 should be the default value, you update the Configuration for the project in the Demo folder. If you do nothing, then the SQL Agent job will still use the locally provided value so you then need to edit the job to remove the locally configured value and use the Project scoped configuration value.

Comment: Can you review this line please `If I created Job2 which runs the same package, it will use 0 and then 2` - why will it use 0 and then 2. It will just use 2, isn't it?

Comment: Also, you have not answered how I can re-establish the link between the project parameter and the job parameter. For example: suppose I mistakenly edit the job parameter then it breaks the link, and future updates to the project parameter do not affect the job parameter. I want to correct this mistake without having to create a new job. Or is creating a new job the only way to establish a link between the project parameter and job parameter?